# Passing version environment variable from build time to runtime in Conda package

Tags: python, conda, conda-build

The version of my package is defined as an envrionment variable (`VERSION`). This environment variable is read by `setup.py` which passes it to `meta.yaml`. This is the version with which my package builds.
When my package is run as `package --version`, users should see this correct version variable value.

My question is: how do I pass this information from an environment variable at the build stage (`VERSION=1.0.0 conda build package`) to the run stage (`conda install package && package --version`)?

I am using a `build.sh` script. One way I thought of was putting `echo $VERSION > version.txt` in `build.sh`. But I do not know if there's a `$PREFIX/static` directory, similar to `$PREFIX/bin`.

Comment: If I understand your question, you're asking how to add a `--version` flag to the CLI of your package? If everything is working as you describe (`package: version:` is set in `meta.yaml` and `conda install package` both work) this should be handled by your package, not `conda`, probably alongside how other arguments are parsed in your CLI.

Comment: I find this situation of version derived from an env var, with no other hard coding in a file to be odd. Playing along with OP proposal, I would think `$PREFIX/etc/<package>/*` would be semantically appropriate for storing configuration info. [Possible relevant docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#specifying-files-to-include-in-output). Still, the idea of an external file defining what the version of a package is doesn't sit quite right - versioning should embed in the binary, IMO.

Comment: @MattThompson Yup, that's what I'm asking about. When you say "this should be handled by your package" could you suggest how to do that?

Comment: @merv If I can I modify one of the source `.py` files at build time to _embed_ the version into it, as you suggest, that's also fine by me. Please suggest a method to do that.

Comment: @GaurangTandon I'm not sure how the rest of your CLI is built, but you should be able to wire up `argparse` or something similar to parse `--version` and return your package's `__version__`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action